# std::is_same gives strange result in using C++17 structured binding

Tags: binding, c++17, traits

I have some simple C++ code (g++ compiler) in which `std::is_same` trait gives (in my opinion) a weird (unexpected) result: `static_assert` below:

```
class Person {
public:
    const std::string _given_name;
    const std::string _surname;
    std::string _nickname;
    Person(const std::string& given_name, const std::string& surname, const std::string& nickname)
        : _given_name(given_name), _surname(surname), _nickname(nickname) {
    }
};

Person p("Donald", "Duck", "?");
auto& [gn, sn, nn] = p; // C++17 binding
nn = "Blondie";
std::cout << p._nickname << std::endl; // 'Blondie'
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(nn), std::string&>::value); // Fails!
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(nn), std::string>::value);  // Succeeds!
```

Answer (score 4):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) about `decltype`:

> If the argument is an ***unparenthesized*** id-expression naming a
>   structured binding, then decltype yields the ***referenced type***
>   (described in the specification of the structured binding
>   declaration).

In your case in fact `decltype` is the culprit, not the structured binding itself (or I guess they are in cahoots). 
So instead you want `decltype((nn))` for your `static_assert` to succeed.

Comment: Thanks DeiDei about this quick reply. Perfectly clear... Unfortunately, C++ remains over-complicated (as usual)...

Comment: Just another remark anyway. I understand the rule, but `nn` is *really* a reference since `nn = "Blondie";` has direct side-effect on `p._nickname`. I already used `decltype((nn))` in another example, so, again, rule is non-debatable. Nonetheless, as a summary, despite this clear rule, I wonder why C++ is designed so "convoluted".

Comment: @Bob C++ is designed to cover an insane amount of use-cases and corner-cases, even if a use-case is extremely remote. I'm not sure why this particular feature was designed this way but there's probably a good reason. If the language was simple, it wouldn't be as useful as it is. There's a lot of history that C++ has to carry as well.

Comment: @Bab If you are satisfied, do please accept this answer so that the question can be marked as solved. Thnx :)